# unexpected characters in smart contract arguments

Tags: tezos-client

The tezos-client seems unhappy with `/` and `.` in my argument:

```
nochem@peck ~/workspace/tezos () $ ./tezos-client --endpoint https://rpc.ghostnet.teztnets.xyz transfer 1 from dictator to KT1GJKrZrVBEFARZi1D3YJxVEJm8sR7Eng5w  --entrypoint 'register' --arg 'https://tz1xf8zdt3.ghostnet.flashbake-endpoint.midl.dev/flashbake/bundle'
Warning:
  
                 This is NOT the Tezos Mainnet.
  
           Do NOT use your fundraiser keys on this network.

At line 1 character 6, unexpected character /
At line 1 character 7, unexpected character /
At line 1 character 18, unexpected character .
At line 1 character 27, unexpected character .
At line 1 characters 37 to 38, unterminated integer
At line 1 character 46, unexpected character .
At line 1 character 51, unexpected character .
At line 1 character 55, unexpected character /
At line 1 character 65, unexpected character /
At line 1 characters 5 to 6, unexpected annotation
Invalid primitive:
  1: https tz1xf8zdt3 ghostnet flashbake endpoint midl dev flashbake bundle
Unknown primitive https.
Fatal error:
  transfer simulation failed
```

How to escape these characters properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes are being interpreted by your shell, you still need double quotes for  Michelson to parse the argument as a string:

```
--arg '"https://tz1xf8zdt3.ghostnet.flashbake-endpoint.midl.dev/flashbake/bundle"'
```

Comment: It worked! thanks